# Galois group of $ \mathbb{Q}(\varepsilon_5) / \mathbb{Q} $

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Let $ L =\mathbb{Q}(\varepsilon_5) $ be an extension of $ \mathbb{Q} $. Find the Galois group $ G(L / \mathbb{Q})$

$ \varepsilon_5  $ is the primitive root of unity of order 5.

Well, I believe that the order of this group is $ 4 $, since

$$ x^5 - 1 = (x-1)(x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1) $$

The second polynomial in this product is irreducible (I'm not sure how to prove it nicely though - it has no real roots, so the only way to reduce it is to multiply two polynomials of order $2$ - I'm guessing the only way is to solve a system of equations and prove the solutions aren't rational)

There are two groups of order $ 4 $. I'm not sure how to determine which one that is. An automorphism of this extension is determined by its value on $ \varepsilon_5 $, which can be only $ \varepsilon_5, \varepsilon_5^2, \varepsilon_5^3, \varepsilon_5^4 $, so I'm guessing the groups will be cyclic, generated by $ \sigma(\varepsilon_5) = \varepsilon_5^2 $.

Does that sound right?

Comment: It's called a cyclotomic polynomial, if you google that you'll find the proof that it's irreducible, it basically uses a change of variables an Eistenstein's criteria.

Comment: I believe you are correct, cyclic of order four, generated by that one you say.

Comment: I looked it up.  In general if you replace $5$ by $n$ then the Galois group is the group of units $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^\times$.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any reference on where to look it up?

Comment: Sure, the wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_field

Comment: The way to show that $(x^p-1)/(x-1)=\varphi(x)$ is irreducible is to expand $\varphi(x+1)$. Best to do it *before* accomplishing the division! (It Eisensteins.)